# Save webview text to clipboard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, clipboardmanager

I have created a WebView, I want to be able to copy the content of the webview with formating to the clipboard.

`recipeDescription.getText().toString` Didn't work because the `recipeDescription` is a WebView not a String.

```
        btnCopy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("recipeDescription", X); //What I should be writing instead of X to get the text from recipeDescription Webview?
            clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

            Toast.makeText(ActivityRecipesDetail.this,"recipeDescription Copied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After several tries I figuration half the solution
X = `htmlData.text(), htmlData.text()`
however the formatting is incorrect (copy all content in one line No break lines)